# Visual Studio Create Resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In my Visual Studio 2015 WPF Project I want to define a new Resource for my UIElement. In the Documentation on the Microsoft Site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921076.aspx) they say that you can choose a ResourceDictionary. 
Following Steps are described:

- Click the UIElement
- On any Property click on the Little square on the right
- Select "Convert to new Resource"
- Choose your Option

In my Project the desired Option is not enabled. The only Option i can set is the "This Document" Option.

My Project has the following Structure.

- Folder "Resources" which contains some XAML Files that hold single ResourceDictionaries
- a ModuleResources.xaml file that merges all the Resource Dictionaries from the Resources Folder together

In the Project Properties i found a Option to define Resources, but those only allow Images/Strins/Icons.

Am i missing something?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Can we gat a screen of your Issue? Cant reproduce on my machine since everything is working as expected

Comment: Still cant figure out whats wrong. Is the **target** a custom control? Where did you place the Control you want to style? Can you apply a Style manually in XAML? Does this also happen if you try this in a new, clean project?

Comment: I have a grid and i tried to set the Property "Opacity" in a new Resource because i dont want to always copy my Stylings manually. This happens with every Property that is defined. I can set my Styling as normal with every Tools there are. Just this one Thing is not working.

Comment: Same Thing happens in other Projects.

Comment: So why don't you just create a new ResourceDictionart and copy the resource over from the current document do this one instead of fighting against the VS designer?

Comment: mm8 has a point. I think it something to do with your system in general. Could be corrupted installation, missing components etc. Hard to tell without knowing your system

Comment: The main idea was to find an easier way of defining the Styles than just copy it each time manually into the right file. This Question is just an idea to make my life easier^^